# How to create a Python 2.7 virtual environment using Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, virtualenv, python-3.7, python-venv

I have Python 3.7 but I would like to create a Python 2.7 virtual environment to run some code that only works on Python 2.7.

How do I create this python 2.7 virtual environment?

```
python3 -m venv
```

Like this?

Answer (score 24):

When creating virtual environment, a `pyvenv.cfg` is created that has `home` key which tells where the python executable is, which was used to create the virtual environment. If your global python installation is version 3.8.6, and you run

```
python3 -m venv something
```

you will create virtual environment in folder `something`, that has `pyvenv.cfg` that points to the `python` executable of the Python 3.8.6 installation. There is no easy way* to make it point to the Python 2.7 executable.

#### What can you do?

**`virtualenv` as `venv` replacement**

The `venv` module was introduced in Python 3.3, so you cannot use it to create virtual environments with python 2.7. You could use the [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/index.html) package which is a superset of `venv`. First, install it with python 2.7**:

```
python -m pip install virtualenv
```

If Python 2.7 is not on your PATH as `python`, use full path to the python executable in place of `python`. Then, you can create virtual environments that have Python 2.7 with

```
virtualenv something
```

or

```bash
virtualenv --python=python2.7 something
```

---

* It is not supported by the [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) module out of the box, at least.
** You can actually install it with *any* Python version, but then you will have to specify `--python=/opt/python-2.7/bin/python` or `--python=python2.7` when running `virtualenv`. By default, it uses the python executable that was used to install it.

Answer (score 0):

`venv` doesn’t allow creating virtual environments with other versions of Python than the one currently installed. You would have to use the traditional [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/installation.html) package which allows creating virtual environments for different versions of python by providing the path to the binary like this:

```bash
virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.7 /path/to/virtualenv/
```

where the path `/usr/bin/python2.7` refers to the path of the binary for Python 2.7 on your system.

Answer (score -1):

Install python2.7

Add universe repo

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe

sudo apt update
```

Install python2.7

```
sudo apt install python2-minimal
```

Create virtualenv with python2.7

```
mkvirtualenv -p $(which python2) something
```

Comment: mkvirtualenv, from where is it?

Comment: from here i guess https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-mkvirtualenv-to-create-new-virtual-environment-python/

Comment: The `apt` stuff is specific to Debian and derivatives; this is very platform-specific advice even in the absence of the undeclared third-party dependency.