# Cannot add python Requests module to OpenRefine

Tags: python, openrefine

I can't seem to import the requests module into OpenRefine . How can I add more python modules to openrefine?

I get the error:

ImportError: No module named requests

screenshot

[image: 1]

Comment: Requests is not part of the python standard library you will likely need to install it in openrefine using a package manager if you haven’t done so

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I can’t figure out how to do that.

Comment: Do you have requests in your local python environment (pip install requests)?

Comment: I couldn’t find any real documentation on this but it might use your local python environment (interpreter and libraries) to execute.

Comment: Yes. Although I'm using python3, which openrefine doesn't support. I originally installed requests by running pip3 install requests

Comment: A hodgepodge of 2 and 3? 2 is severely deprecated… I think you can install 2 alongside three and just manually reference the interpreter somehow or overwrite the global term “python” your terminal uses so it knows what version to reference. I’m not sure how but maybe a venv would work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65685217/how-to-create-python-2-7-virtual-environment-using-python-3-7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenRefine is using [Jython](https://www.jython.org/), a Java implementation of Python. Therefore, you can not "just" install another library/package.

There is a tutorial in the OpenRefine wiki describing [how to extend Jython with PyPi modules](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Extending-Jython-with-pypi-modules).

Please note that currently 2.7 is the newest Jython implementation. Jython 3 is still in it's planing and development phase. See [Jython 3 Roadmap](https://www.jython.org/jython-3-roadmap) for details. This makes it difficult to use external libraries, as Python 2 had its end of life on 01.01.2020 and accordingly (most) libraries stopped supporting Python 2.

For requests the [last version that supports Python 2 is 2.27](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/community/faq/#python-2-support).

Also, some Python packages rely on C libraries that are not compatible with Jython. Check the [Appendix A of the Definitive Guide to Jython](https://jython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/appendixA/) for more details on using external tools and libraries.